# Translator functionality in Tapestry5 Grid Componenet

Tags: java, tapestry

Today I will have question regarding formatting numbers in Tapestry5 grid.
I have couple of fields in [Grid](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.html) component that I need to format due to some rules that concerns decimal mark and thousands separator. For textfields I'm using translator defined for whole application (like in [this](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/input/contributingtranslators) example) but I have no idea how to get same functionality for grid (or even if it is possible at all).I would like to have same mechanism available for all grids in my whole applications.

Of course not all numeric grid field will be currencies so there should be some kind of possibility to configure them.

I know that with grid I can use ValueEncoder but I think that this won't work in that case because it encodes whole object displayed in grid, not only some defined fields.

One more thing: I know that I can define each field to get value from method and there do all functionality, but I'm looking for something more flexible - like mentioned earlier "translator" for textfields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by the combination of a few things

1. A [DataTypeAnalyzer](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/DataTypeAnalyzer.html) which produces a String datatype given a [PropertyAdapter](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ioc/services/PropertyAdapter.html)
2. A [DisplayBlockContribution](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/DisplayBlockContribution.html) which maps the datatype to a block (see also EditBlockContribution).
3. Contribute the DisplayBlockContribution to the BeanBlockSource

Note that this will not only affect the grid, it will also affect all bean based components (eg BeanDisplay).

Jumpstart example [here](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/lang/propertyeditors)

Comment: You could probably drive the datatype using an annotation on the fields which can be looked up by your DataTypeAnalyzer. Eg @DecimalFormat("#,##0.00")

Comment: Hmm don't know if I get you right: DataTypeAnalyzer should look for some kind of annotation?

Comment: Well, in mean time I do it in a other way: I've written my own DataTypeAnalyzer (quite similar to AnnotationDataType Analyzer) and this started to working too. Nevertheless thanks for your tips too :)

Comment: Oh, cool... I didn't know about the @DataType annotation. If you use these annotations on your bean you won't need a custom DataTypeAnalyzer. Just use @DataType("4decimalplaces") etc.

Comment: Point for you. I haven't read AnnotationDataTypeAnalyzer doc carefully and you are right that this is all I need - thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default grid cell rendering behaviour by defining a block property named xCell (where x is the column name). The [documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.html) gives an example of customising rendering of the lastName column.

```
<t:grid source="users" row="user">
    <p:lastNameCell>
        <t:pagelink page="user/view" context="user.id">${user.lastname}</t:pagelink>
    </p:lastNameCell>
</t:grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the problem with that solution is that I would need to repeat code for column in every single grid, and I would like to write in one place and only propagate all over app.